# Angry about vs angry for!

Tags: grammar

Look  these below sentences:

> He is angry about the fact
>
> He is angry for the fact

why I can't say *angry for* instead of saying *angry about*?

Answer (score 3):

The choice of prepositions in all contexts has been established by convention rather than any rules.

The most suitable preposition to follow **angry** depends on what follows:

> He is angry *with* me.
>
> He is angry *at* his failure.
>
> He is angry *on* my behalf.
>
> He has been angry *for* days.

There are other possibilities too. But in the example that you give, *about* is the correct choice. If you used *for*, it would not sound idiomatic.

Finally, it's a little unusual to be *angry about facts* as these are just statements of reality. He could be *angry about the fact that he had failed* but it would be simpler to write that he *was angry about his failure*.

Comment: Yes. Other constructions (which are more situational) are *he felt sorry* ***for*** *her* and *he failed, and he was angry about* ***that***.